# How should I share data structures

Tags: c++, oop

> Bjarne Stroustrup: My rule of thumb is that you should have a real
>   class with an interface and a hidden representation if and only if you
>   can consider an invariant for the class.

On a current project, I had a base class called Widget. It had private variables for x, y, width, height (basically a rect data structure) and public getters and setters for each. Their was no purpose to the class except being a dumb variable holder. In light of Bjarnes' comment above, I got rid of this class, but I'm wondering how I should share this data structure with child classes that need them. Should I just individually include them as members for each class? Put them inside a Widget namespace?

Comment: Well his comment says "have a real class **with an interface and a hidden representation** only if [..]" so he's not talking about classes in general. While I'd prefer a struct too for a simple datastructure without any real functions, that is almost purely subjective (no real difference between structs and classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you massively misread Stroustrup there, let me emphasise the part that I think is important:

> My rule of thumb is that you should have a **real** class **with an interface and a hidden representation** if and only if you can consider an invariant for the class.

I believe he is specifically not talking about not using the *keyword `class`* in this situation but is referring to a *logical class* (or "real class"). The difference is quite significant. A class <sup>(note the lack of markdown)</sup> is a data structure with a self contained interface and possibly a hidden implementation (see pimpl idiom). That means, the workings of a (logical) class are invisible to the user and a class object is communicated with via member functions and free functions. In terms of data abstraction that is sometimes interpreted as "don't access member variables from the outside" but that's just a shallower wording of the core idea.

You should still use structured design for heterogeneous collections of data just as you do (or as [Commander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13326750/430766) or [Dietmar Kühl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13326796/430766) suggests). Whether or not you use the `class` or the `struct` keyword is personal taste, but I tend to use the `struct` keyword so it is clear that this type is *not* a class in the logical sense but just some data that belongs together. I find using a proper struct is preferable to an `std::tuple` as you can name all the members, giving them meaning, rather than accessing them by index and having to remember what every index was supposed to mean. In addition it is easier to modify and extend a `struct` in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a struct

e.g.

```
struct widget
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
};
```

Comment: This being C++, most people would recommend classes.

Comment: He originally had a class and got rid of it because it doesn't do anything except hold 4 values. So, if you don't want a class then use a struct. Otherwise, pass 4 values around every time you call functions against a "widget".

Comment: not in all cases, structs can be more useful when you only need to create objects that hold data.

Comment: @Wug: No they wont. It is very common to keep plain old data and even non-pod data in `struct`s if the object doesn't some functionality.

Comment: Apart from being public by default there isn't any difference between structs and classes in c++ (that I'm aware of right now at least), so this really amounts to nothing more than personal preference. I do like to use structs for dumb data structures too.

Comment: Overall i'm fairly sure it comes down to preference. My preference is to use structs if your not defining any functions in your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely agree with Bjarne (aside from invariants the ability to change the representation may be an important concern although in that case it may be important to even move the actual definition into a [PImpl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) rather than just making it `private`). However, you can group variables into a structure with `public` access to its members if there is no concern about changed members and or invariants. In case, the members are indeed just lumped together without a semantic meaning, you might even just use a `std::tuple`:

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int, double, double> widget;
```

... although in this case the different members do have access functions - for technical reasons independent from invariants and forward compatibility.